# windows 7 Mirror Failed Redundancy

Tags: windows-7, raid, software-raid, mirror

I've been trying to setup software Mirror RAID using the Windows 7 Disk Manager. However I'm getting the "Failed Redundancy" error no matter what I do.

I think the exclamation icon is appearing on the drive I'm using as the mirror. The second disk is brand new and identical but one disk must have a bad block I assume.

How do I find out which drive and can I repair it?

Comment: How are you adding the second drive? We need more details as to how you're getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I cannot answer your question, but I would say that Microsoft software RAID has never been a good idea, but I would leave open the possibility that it has gotten better since I last played with it.

Is there any way your system can support hardware RAID? So many today do right out of the box.

Comment: I think it might but i already have data on one drive, and I'm attempting to keep it there.